# What's the name for a "multi page scrolling webpage?"

Tags: website-design, terminology, website-templates

A lot of tech companies have a websites with the following UI features:

- a homepage containing several discrete "slides" stacked vertically
- you can scroll vertically through the slides
- or, (in some cases) you can use the navigation bar at the top to jump to a specific slide

I'm interested in finding templates for this type of website. But, I don't know what to search for. **Is there a *name* for web designs that have these features?**

---

Here are a few **examples** of what I'm talking about:

https://keen.io

http://www.clarifai.com

https://www.metamind.io

http://tiffzhang.com/startup <--- anything from the startup website generator

Comment: I call them "trendy"

Comment: What you describe in the title does not match what you describe in the question body...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called one page website or single page website.

Sometimes this are enriched with things like "lazy load", which is loading aditional content when you scroll down, "fixed menus", and "smooth scroll".

Comment: AKA "really annoying" :)

Comment: There is a website dedicated to them here: https://onepagelove.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think its a single page website or 'pageless' designed website but you also hear people using the term parallax when describing similar websites. Parallax means the image behind moves separate to the front. You can read more about it here [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling)

Comment: Parallax is an effect with backgrounds and planes, but it is **not** the fact that a page has different sections.